# How to append rows with google sheet api v4 in nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I really don't get how I can write new rows with the apiv4.

let's say I have a table with the columns *ID, name, count, size*.

The official nodejs example looks like this:

```
let values = [
  [
    // Cell values ...
  ],
  // Additional rows ...
];
let resource = {
  values,
};
this.sheetsService.spreadsheets.values.append({
  spreadsheetId,
  range,
  valueInputOption,
  resource,
}, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error.
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(`${result.updates.updatedCells} cells appended.`);
  }
});
```

So for this to work I need the variables ***values***, ***spreadsheetId***, ***range*** and ***valueInputOption***.

For ***value*** it says that the cell values go in there. Does this mean it must be filled with order from left to right? like with my example:

```
let values = [
      [
        "h7Bfhi87gBjh7fs9", //first the id
        "Max", //then name
        "20", //count
        "500" //size
      ]
    ];
```

Would this be correct?

***spreadsheetId*** do I already have.

For the last two variables I don't know what they mean.

First the ***range*** variable. For reading, you must give the function a range to read from, that is simple. But Why do I need a range if I want to append rows to the table?

Second, I have no clue what ***valueInputOption*** does.

---

tldr:

What values do I need to declare to the variables ***values***, ***range*** and ***valueInputOptions*** if I want to append rows to a spreadsheet with google spreadsheet apiv4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Values** is an array of data to go into the cells.

**Range** is the address of the cells where the data needs to go to.

**valueInputOptions** could be `raw`. See [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption).

---

**Edited:**

Try to replace:

```
this.sheetsService.spreadsheets.values.append({
  spreadsheetId,
  range,
  valueInputOption,
  resource,
}
```

with

```
this.sheetsService.spreadsheets.values.append({
  spreadsheetId: 'string_spreadsheet_ID',
  range: 'Sheet1!A1:D1', // Or where you need the data to go 
  valueInputOption: 'RAW',
  resource: resource // takes the array created in the lines earlier
}
```

See [this page](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) for hints on the code structure.

Comment: So `valueinputOption = ValueinputOptions.raw;` ?
 For value, I think its right how I did it in my question but I still don't get what Range needs, I just want to append the rows on the end of the table.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to *append rows at the end*, you can specify "Sheet1" (or whatever the name of the sheet your want to append to) for the range (cf https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#appending_values).